# SharePoint: Can a Content Type have an attachments collection property?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a content type, that will store text site columns, and I want to know if its possible to have an attachments collection? This I guess could be stored in some folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All content types that don't inherit from Document automatically have an attachments collection: [SPListItem.Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx)

> The **Attachments** property does not apply to document libraries and returns an **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** exception if applied to a document library.

Comment: Sounds good, can a list item also have a site Column which is of type file?

Comment: No, your only file attachment options are a "list item" with Attachments or a "document" with a single attachment that gets special treatment. And of course, with a custom field type you can do just about anything.